# what would be the regex pattern to identify in text citation - "(author name , year)'?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have converted list of tokenized sentences to a dataframe. Now, I need to filter the rows (sentences) that has citation in it.

Example dataframe:

```
   sentences
1  This is my house
2  This is clear water(World Health organisation, 2018).
3  This house was built in 2000 
4  According to me (Sundar, 2015)it is good.
```

Expected Output:

```
   sentences
1  This is clear water(World Health organisation, 2018).
2  According to me (Sundar, 2015)it is good.
```

I have been using the below code with different patterns, r'[(]\w+,\d{4}[)]', r"[(\w+\s+, \d{4})]

```
df[df['sentences'].str.contains(r'\d{4}', regex = True)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try :

```
print(df[df['sentences'].str.contains(r'\d{4}\)', regex = True)])
```

Or:

```
print(df[df['sentences'].str.contains(r'\w.+\(\w.+\d{4}\)', regex = True)])
```

Both outputs:

```
                                               sentences
2  This is clear water(World Health organisation, 2018).
4              According to me (Sundar, 2015)it is good.
```

Comment: Glad it helps you! Could you [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)?